# LIRC and Raspberry OS Bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, lirc

I have a problem with Raspberry PI 3 with Bullseye Raspberry OS.
Apparently with the newest version of lirc 0.10.1-6.3 which already contains patch described here: https://gist.github.com/billpatrianakos/cb72e984d4730043fe79cbe5fc8f7941

With my configuration when I run:

```
mode2 -d /dev/lirc1
```

I can see IR codes normally:

[image]

However

```
irrecord -d /dev/lirc0 ~/lircd+ts.conf
```

Gives me incorrect output.
[image]

**I read that with newest kernels LIRC is deprecated, have you had any success with LIRC on Bullseye?
What I should also mentioned that with Rapbian Jessie with the same hardware it all worked, but Jessie didn't use gpio**

I even tried to use on Bullseye those mappings (https://github.com/tscislo/internet-radio-raspberry-pi/blob/master/config/lirc/.lircrc) that I generated on Jessie and they work sometimes, but when I use irw my success rate is 4/10 recognized RC button clicks. With exactly the same hardware and exactly the same RC on Jessie I get 10/10.

Do you have any clues?

Comment: Finally I was able to use GPIO with this library: https://pypi.org/project/PiIR/ You can find my code here:
https://github.com/tscislo/internet-radio-raspberry-pi/blob/master/threads/rcThread.py